# java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()

Tags: android

Assim que o usuário informar algum dado sobre o livro, o app exibi uma lista da API da Google Books com informações sobre o livro, estava fazendo uns testes e algumas palavras retornam corretamente a listagem e tal, mas algumas palavras como "Paixão" por exemplo, trava o app e retorna esse erro.

Requisição Atualizado

```
package com.example.android.listadelivros;

import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public final class ConsultaRequisicao {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = ConsultaRequisicao.class.getSimpleName();

    private ConsultaRequisicao() {
    }

    public static List<DadosLivro> buscarDadosLivro(String pedidoUrl) {

        URL url = criarUrl(pedidoUrl);

        String jsonResposta = null;
        try {
            jsonResposta = fazerPedidoHttp(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problemar ao criar um pedido HTTP.", e);
        }

        List<DadosLivro> livros = extrairDadosJson(jsonResposta);
        return livros;
    }

    private static URL criarUrl(String stringUrl) {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(stringUrl);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problema na contrução da URL.", e);
        }
        return url;
    }

    private static String fazerPedidoHttp(URL url) throws IOException {

        String jsonResposta = "";

        if (url == null) {
            return jsonResposta;
        }

        HttpURLConnection conexao = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;

        try {
            conexao = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conexao.setReadTimeout(1000);
            conexao.setConnectTimeout(1500);
            conexao.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conexao.connect();

            if (conexao.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                inputStream = conexao.getInputStream();
                jsonResposta = converterInputStream(inputStream);
            } else {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Erro na resposta do código: " + conexao.getResponseCode());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problemas ao recuperar o resultado dos livros - JSON " + e);
        } finally {
            if (conexao != null) {
                conexao.disconnect();
            }
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }
        }
        return jsonResposta;
    }


    private static String converterInputStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder saida = new StringBuilder();

        if (inputStream != null) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            BufferedReader ler = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

            String linha = ler.readLine();
            while (linha != null) {
                saida.append(linha);
                linha = ler.readLine();
            }
        }
        return saida.toString();
    }

    private static List<DadosLivro> extrairDadosJson(String dadosLivrosJson) {

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(dadosLivrosJson)) {
            return null;
        }

        List<DadosLivro> informacoesLivro = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            JSONObject respostaJason = new JSONObject(dadosLivrosJson);
            JSONArray dadosLivroArray = respostaJason.optJSONArray("items");

            for (int i = 0; i < dadosLivroArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject livroAtual = dadosLivroArray.optJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject informacaoVolume = livroAtual.optJSONObject("volumeInfo");

                String titulo = informacaoVolume.optString("title");
                String descricao = informacaoVolume.optString("description");

                JSONArray listaAutor = informacaoVolume.optJSONArray("authors");
                String autor = (String) listaAutor.get(0);

                DadosLivro inforLivro = new DadosLivro(titulo, descricao, autor);
                informacoesLivro.add(inforLivro);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problema ao analisar os resultados JSON", e);
        }
        return informacoesLivro;
    }
}
```

Erro

```
at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:312)
                                                                                           at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:69)
                                                                                           at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:66)
                                                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                                           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
05-09 14:59:12.901 25630-25785/com.example.android.listadelivros E/ConsultaRequisicao: Problema ao analisar os resultados JSON
                                                                                       org.json.JSONException: No value for authors
                                                                                           at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
                                                                                           at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:584)
                                                                                           at com.example.android.listadelivros.ConsultaRequisicao.extrairDadosJson(ConsultaRequisicao.java:127)
                                                                                           at com.example.android.listadelivros.ConsultaRequisicao.buscarDadosLivro(ConsultaRequisicao.java:39)
                                                                                           at com.example.android.listadelivros.DadosLivrosLoader.loadInBackground(DadosLivrosLoader.java:31)
                                                                                           at com.example.android.listadelivros.DadosLivrosLoader.loadInBackground(DadosLivrosLoader.java:9)
                                                                                           at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:312)
                                                                                           at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:69)
                                                                                           at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:66)
                                                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                                           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Por favor, poste o texto do erro ao invés de uma imagem.

Comment: se for pra identar como código, ta feito.

Comment: @ramaral desculpe sobrescrever a edição, acabei não percebendo

Comment: sem problemas, sou nova por aqui, não sei ao certo como funcionam as coisas

Comment: Aline, o erro diz `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object org.json.JSONArray.get(int)' on a null object reference`

Comment: Você não consegue debuggar o código? O erro deve estar no método `extrairDadosJson`?

Comment: sim, fiz isso e não está nulo, simplesmente na hora `return informacoesLivro;`  ele trava, mas está recebendo valores.

Comment: @jbueno postei o debug, não sei se é dessa forma, mas lá vc consegue ver os dados sendo extraido corretamente.

Comment: Mas é neste momento que ocorre o erro?

Comment: ele puxa os dados corretamente e exibe a mensagem `Object has been collected Cannot evaluate org.json.JSONObject.toString()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não inicializou seu JSONArray listaAutor corretamente.

Elimine a linha:

```
JSONArray listaAutor = null;
```

E substitua a linha que alimenta essa variável por:

```
JSONArray listaAutor = informacaoVolume.optJSONArray("authors");
```

Comment: ja havia feito isso e o erro continua, ele retorna o valor do JSON corretamente, porém aparece o mesmo erro.

`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object org.json.JSONArray.get(int)' on a null object reference`

Comment: Faz essa alteração que falei e edita a pergunta com o código e o erro completo atualizados pra ver exatamente onde está o erro. Do jeito que está na pergunta, o erro se dá por conta dessa inicialização do objeto com null e, se ainda continua após a edição que sugeri, o método optJSONArray() pode estar retornando null e aí vai dar erro no get() seguinte mesmo.

Comment: tudo bem, vou fazer, o engraçado é que se vc inserir algumas palavras, ele funciona perfeitamente e com outras, ele simplesmente fecha. Já altero a pergunta. obg

Comment: Vi aqui e edição. O erro realmente está no get() porque o optJSONArray() deve ter retornado nulo. Eu já trabalhei uma vez com a Google Books API. Os autores eu pegava da seguinte forma: String authors = volumeInfo.getJSONArray("authors").join(", ").replace("\"", "");

Comment: amigo, deu certo! Que alivio r obrigada mesmo, ele ta funcionando, mas tbm esta lancando uma excessao, vou editar pra que tu veja.

Comment: Vendo aqui a documentação do JSONArray, talvez você deveria ter usado o método getString(0) em vez do get(0).

Comment: mas se eu fizer isso, apresenta o erro  `Problema ao analisar os resultados JSON                                                                                       org.json.JSONException: No value for authors`

Comment: Estou vendo aqui a exceção nova. Como você deve ter usado getJSONArray em vez de optJSONArray, ele gera uma exceção quando não encontra a string "authors" no JSON. Já o método optJSONArray retorna nulo simplesmente e não gera exceção, mas vai dar erro na linha seguinte se você não checar a variável listaAutor antes de tentar usar get() ou getString(). Minha conclusão é que algum livro retornado pela API não tem autor definido, então o seu método está crasheando porque não está tratando essa possibilidade.

Comment: Usei opt Sim

  `JSONArray listaAutor = informacaoVolume.optJSONArray("authors");`

Comment: Sabe me dizer pq a api retorna apenas 10 itens no listVie? pq provavelmente devem ter dezenas

Comment: Editei minha resposta anterior. Retorna 10 livros porque é o limite para chaves gratuitas.

Comment: obrigada mesmo, vou fazer a verificação do array e ver se resolve. :)